# _triggers dataLayer variable blocks tag from firing on some pages only

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm using Google Tag Manager to send a custom event on click of any Contact Us button or email link. The tag fires as expected on the homepage, but is blocked by a `_triggers` variable on another page. What might be generateing the `_triggers` variable and what questions should I ask the developers?

The trigger is configured like so:
[image: trigger configuration]

Using the preview debugging screen, I tested the tag on two different pages. It fires on the main page, but is blocked by a dataLayer _triggers variable on the other page.

The tag fires successfully on one page:
[image: firing triggers (successful)]

The tag fails on another page:
[image: firing triggers (fail)]